# Ember duplicate loading for models

Tags: ember.js

I want to use the information already received within a linked template.  Nesting routes has created a whole heap of errors, and I'm a little lost on how to pass this data, but it seems like it must be possible?

This works, but strikes me as a poor hack.  Ideally I'd only want one API round-trip...

```
App.Router.map ->
  @resource 'photos'
  @route 'photo', path: 'photo/:photo_id'


App.PhotosRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
    Ember.$.getJSON('http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=cake&tagmode=all&format=json&jsoncallback=?')

  setupController: (controller,model) ->
    controller.set 'photos', model.items.map (i) ->
      i.id = model.items.indexOf(i)


App.PhotoRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params) ->
    jQuery.getJSON('http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=cake&tagmode=all&format=json&jsoncallback=?').then (api) ->
      api.items[params.photo_id]

App.PhotosController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  itemController: 'photo'
```

---

```
{{#linkTo 'photo' this }}<img {{bindAttr src="media.m"}} />{{/linkTo}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `modelFor(routeName)` to get the model from some route. In your case probally you will fetch all data in `PhotosRoute`, and want to reuse it. You can use this in your `PhotoRoute`:

```
App.PhotoRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params) ->
    @modelFor('photos').items[params.photo_id]
```

So just one api call will be done.

Comment: thank you - this works.  However, it fails if i hit refresh.  Is this normal behaviour for Ember or can i use a fallback for events where one ends up at /photo/1 without going through /photos?

Comment: You have 2 options. 1- In your photo route model method, make a find by id in the api, I don't know if this is avaliable in your case. 2- Nest your photo route inside of photos route like [this](http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1928/edit) so when transitioning to photo route, first will be transitioned to all parent routes, in tht case photos. And you will have the data. You will need to update the links to `link-to "photos.photo"`, if you want to use just "photo" you can change `@route 'photo', path: 'photo/:photo_id'` to `@resource 'photo', path: 'photo/:photo_id'`